# ```Custom Module - How to Link to/access its Template Path File

Tags: module, magento-1, custom

I have created and enabled a custom module in my magento store called 'Earnings' to allocate customers loyalty points. I declare the phtml file to use `(template/earnings/earnings.phtml)` in my `earnings.xml` as below

earnings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <earnings_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="earnings/earnings" name="earnings" />
        </reference>
    </earnings_index_index>
</layout>
```

I want the page that uses this template file to be linked from the customer account navigation when they log in (same place as my addresses/my billing agreements/my orders etc). In my local.xml i use addLink as below:

local.xml

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="sidebar">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>reorder</name></action>
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="earnings"><name>earnings</name><path>earnings/earnings/</path><label>Earnings</label></action>
        </block>
        <remove name="tags_popular"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Now when i log into the customer account the link is there,it goes to the url `http://www.example.com/earnings/earnings`
but this gives my a 404 page not found

I am very new to magento and this is  my first go at creating custom modules. Am i missing something or doing something in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

This is the path reference that you are provided in a layout file

```
<path>earnings/earnings/</path>
```

This will set your link to this path `http://www.website.com/earnings/earnings`. When Magento looks for this path, it cannot find a valid controller definition. That is why it throws `404 error`. So set your path to

```
  <path>earnings/</path>
         or
   <path>earnings/index/</path>
```

will solve your issue. Now the link looks like `http://www.website.com/earnings/index/`. You have defined your block for this specific URL. Note you have used `earning_index_index` handle in your layout file. This handle will be processed by Magento only when `http://www.website.com/earnings/index/` URL get requested.

Note: In order to work this URL perfectly, you should have an `IndexController.php` is defined for your module and this file should hold this method.

```
public function indexAction() {

   $this->loadLayout();
   $this->renderLayout();
}
```

If this method and this file are not defined for your module, Magento will throw `404 error` again.